# How to summarize a set of rows and set a boolean based on a primary key and get a result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 rows having same key, I need to return as 'NO' if it doesnt contain the same value for all the rows having same key.

In this below table, The bool value for No 999 shoud be "No" as the Val for this records having the No 999 is same. The bool should be "Yes" if the value for that same No key has different value.
For 538 the val has 0,30,0 so the bool is "Yes"
For 422 the val has 30,30,30 so the bool is "No"

| No | Name | Mat | Val | Bool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | AURO | NULL | 0 | Yes |
| 999 | AURO | 49790 | 0 | Yes |
| 999 | AURO | 53383 | 0 | Yes |
| 422 | BIO | 87103 | 30 | No |
| 422 | BIO | 87047 | 30 | No |
| 422 | BIO | 87100 | 30 | No |
| 538 | NOVA | 57819 | 0 | Yes |
| 538 | NOVA | 57850 | 30 | Yes |
| 538 | NOVA | 57788 | 0 | Yes |

Solution i tried:

```
SELECT [No], [Name],Mat, val, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY No) =
            COUNT(Mat) OVER (PARTITION BY No) 
            AND MAX(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No) = 
                MIN(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No)
            THEN 'No'
            WHEN COUNT(Mat) OVER (PARTITION BY No) > 0
            THEN 'Yes'     
       END AS Bool
FROM personal_table
```

Getting desired result if i use the below query but i am not sure the logic i am intended to use is correct or not

```
    SELECT [No], [Name],Mat, val, 
       CASE WHEN  MAX(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No) = 
                MIN(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No)
            THEN 'No'
            WHEN COUNT(Mat) OVER (PARTITION BY No) > 0
            THEN 'Yes'     
       END AS Bool
  FROM personal_table
```

Thank You

Comment: Yes comparing `MAX` and `MIN` is an efficient way to check if there are at least two different values in the partition. And you don't need a predicate for the `'Yes`' branch, it should be just `ELSE 'Yes'`.

Comment: your description doesn't match your data, 999 has yes, but you write no. your query involves Mat for some reason

Comment: @GMB I am getting "Yes" for the first set of records ie for the No 999 so ho can we address that. Just wanted to check.

Comment: @Siggemannen _ The table has the values i am getting from the solution i have tried , The second solution will give you "No" value , Just wanted to check what is the efficient way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, i added some alternative solutions. COUNT DISTINCT can be a bit expensive, so the MAX = MIN version should be fine too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd do it with a subjoin against the aggregated set:

```sql
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (999, N'AURO', N'NULL', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (999, N'AURO', N'49790', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (999, N'AURO', N'53383', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (422, N'BIO', N'87103', 30, N'No')
        ,   (422, N'BIO', N'87047', 30, N'No')
        ,   (422, N'BIO', N'87100', 30, N'No')
        ,   (538, N'NOVA', N'57819', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (538, N'NOVA', N'57850', 30, N'Yes')
        ,   (538, N'NOVA', N'57788', 0, N'Yes')
    ) t (No,Name,Mat,Val,Bool)
    )
SELECT  c.NO, c.Name, c.Mat, c.Val
,   CASE WHEN valcount = 1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
FROM    cte c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  count(DISTINCT val) AS valCount
    ,   NO
    FROM    cte c2
    GROUP BY no
    ) x
    ON  x.NO = c.No
```

Basically, you calculate the aggregate parts and then join it back to check if all values are distinct. Same can be achieved by a subquery:

```sql
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (999, N'AURO', N'NULL', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (999, N'AURO', N'49790', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (999, N'AURO', N'53383', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (422, N'BIO', N'87103', 30, N'No')
        ,   (422, N'BIO', N'87047', 30, N'No')
        ,   (422, N'BIO', N'87100', 30, N'No')
        ,   (538, N'NOVA', N'57819', 0, N'Yes')
        ,   (538, N'NOVA', N'57850', 30, N'Yes')
        ,   (538, N'NOVA', N'57788', 0, N'Yes')
    ) t (No,Name,Mat,Val,Bool)
    )
SELECT  c.NO, c.Name, c.Mat, c.Val
,   CASE WHEN (SELECT count(DISTINCT val) AS valCount FROM  cte c2 where c2.NO = c.NO) = 1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
FROM    cte c
```

Comment: Thanks @Siggemannen - Marking this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the `MIN` with the `MAX`. You need to take into account nulls.

You can use the new `IS DISTINCT FROM` for a nullable compare

```sql
SELECT
  [No],
  Name,
  Mat,
  val, 
  CASE WHEN
    MAX(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No) IS DISTINCT FROM
    MIN(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No)
    THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
  END AS Bool
FROM personal_table;
```

Or on older versions use

```
  CASE WHEN
    ISNULL(MAX(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No), 0) =
    ISNULL(MIN(val) OVER (PARTITION BY No), 0)
```